# SQL get one time customers by email field

Tags: mysql, sql, timeout

I have a database with over 100,000 records. I'm trying to get all customers who ordered only once searching by customer's email field (`OrderEmail`).

The SQL query is running for 10 minutes and then times out.

If I use short date ranges, I can get results but it still takes over 3 minutes.

How can I optimize the syntax to get it work?

```
SELECT 
    tblOrders.OrderID,
    tblOrders.OrderName,
    tblOrders.OrderEmail,
    tblOrders.OrderPhone,
    tblOrders.OrderCountry,
    tblOrders.OrderDate
FROM
    tblOrders
LEFT JOIN tblOrders AS orders_join ON orders_join.OrderEmail = tblOrders.OrderEmail
    AND NOT orders_join.OrderID = tblOrders.OrderID
WHERE
    orders_join.OrderID IS NULL
    AND (tblOrders.OrderDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-03-01')
    AND tblOrders.OrderDelivered = - 1
ORDER BY
    tblOrders.OrderID ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the below to work - but I can't test it as you don't provide sample data. Well, I added a temporary table definition that could be used for the query ....

But , if you could actually change the data model to use an INTEGER id for the entity who placed the order (instead of a VARCHAR() email address), you would get considerably faster.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
tblorders(orderid,ordername,orderemail,orderphone,ordercountry,orderdate) AS (
            SELECT  1,'ORD01','adent@hog.com' ,'9-991' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-01'
  UNION ALL SELECT  2,'ORD02','tricia@hog.com','9-992' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-02'
  UNION ALL SELECT  3,'ORD03','ford@hog.com'  ,'9-993' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-03'
  UNION ALL SELECT  4,'ORD04','zaphod@hog.com','9-9943','UK', DATE '2017-01-04'
  UNION ALL SELECT  5,'ORD05','marvin@hog.com','9-9942','UK', DATE '2017-01-05'
  UNION ALL SELECT  6,'ORD06','ford@hog.com'  ,'9-993' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-06'
  UNION ALL SELECT  7,'ORD07','tricia@hog.com','9-992' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-07'
  UNION ALL SELECT  8,'ORD08','benji@hog.com' ,'9-995' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-08'
  UNION ALL SELECT  9,'ORD09','benji@hog.com' ,'9-995' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-09'
  UNION ALL SELECT 10,'ORD10','ford@hog.com'  ,'9-993' ,'UK', DATE '2017-01-10'
)
;

SELECT 
  tblOrders.OrderID
, tblOrders.OrderName
, tblOrders.OrderEmail
, tblOrders.OrderPhone
, tblOrders.OrderCountry
, tblOrders.OrderDate
FROM tblOrders
JOIN (
  SELECT
      OrderEmail
    FROM tblOrders
    GROUP BY
      OrderEmail
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) singleOrders
ON singleOrders.OrderEmail = tblOrders.OrderEmail
    ORDER BY OrderID
;

OrderID|OrderName|OrderEmail    |OrderPhone|OrderCountry|OrderDate
      1|ORD01    |adent@hog.com |9-991     |UK          |2017-01-01
      4|ORD04    |zaphod@hog.com|9-9943    |UK          |2017-01-04
      5|ORD05    |marvin@hog.com|9-9942    |UK          |2017-01-05
```

As you can see, it returns Mr. Dent, Zaphod and Marvin, who all occur only once in the example data.

Comment: Works like a charm !! Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Another approach that might work is that you group by email address and get only those with one entry. It may behave unpredictably if you want to get customers with multiple orders but it should be fine for this particular case:

```
SELECT 
    tblOrders.OrderID,
    tblOrders.OrderName,
    tblOrders.OrderEmail,
    tblOrders.OrderPhone,
    tblOrders.OrderCountry,
    tblOrders.OrderDate,
    count(tblOrders.OrderID) as OrderCount
FROM
    tblOrders
WHERE
    tblOrders.OrderDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-03-01'
    AND tblOrders.OrderDelivered = - 1
GROUP BY
    tblOrders.OrderEmail
HAVING
    OrderCount = 1
ORDER BY
    tblOrders.OrderID ASC;
```

Also, I suspect that if you're seeing so long query times with just 100k records, you probably don't have an index on the OrderEmail column - I suggest setting that up and that might help with your original queries as well.

This does not work in Oracle, or SQL Server but it does work in MySQL and SQLite. So, while the code is not portable between different RDBMS, it works *for this particular case*.

Comment: This will not work. All columns you put in the select which are no aggregations must also be in the group by clause.

Comment: @Conffusion It may not work in proper SQL but it does work in MySQL with its numerous idiosyncracies. I tested a similar query. It will group by that column but it will return the data from the first record for the ungrouped columns, which is what you need in this particular case.

Comment: pilsetnieks, thanks for the clarification; learned something new today +1